# Unlist the list into vector and use elements as columns in R(if possible without loops)

Tags: r, igraph

I am using the `ego` from `igraph` to get neighbors of nodes. My input is in the following format

```
  V1  V2
1    9   7
2    9  10
3    9  84
4    7   8
5    7   9
6    7  79
7   10   9
8   10  11
9   10  84
10  10 110
```

Then i am performing the following operations on this input (here `rd` is the input csv file)

```
gs <- graph.data.frame(rd, directed = FALSE)
q<-ego(gs,2,(1:20))
```

The output of q is in form of list as(output for first 5 nodes of graph)

```
[[1]]
+ 10/20 vertices, named:
 [1] 9   7   10  84  8   79  11  110 83  85 

[[2]]
+ 9/20 vertices, named:
[1] 7   9   8   79  10  84  33  78  119

[[3]]
+ 11/20 vertices, named:
 [1] 10  9   84  11  110 7   83  85  12  111 112

[[4]]
+ 8/20 vertices, named:
[1] 84  9   10  83  85  7   11  110

[[5]]
+ 7/20 vertices, named:
[1] 8  7  33 9  79 32 34
```

Here the first element represents the node on which operation is performed.
The output i want is to get a dataframe in such a way that first element of every vector in first column and rest of elements of every vector in the second column
for example for first and second vector in the given output

```
 
    V1  V2
1    9  7
2    9  10
3    9  84
4    9   8
5    9  79
6    9  11
7    9  110
8    9  83
9    9  85
10   7  8
11   7  9
12   7  79
13   7  10
14   7  84
15   7  33
16   7  78
17   7  119
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is helpful if you provide a reproducible example that replicates your problem. For example, something as simple as

```
myList <- list(1:10, 2:11)
```

should suffice.

At this point, you can use some hidden loops with `lapply` and `do.call` to construct your desired output.

```
do.call(rbind.data.frame, lapply(myList, function(x) cbind(x[1], x[-1])))
   V1 V2
1   1  2
2   1  3
3   1  4
4   1  5
5   1  6
6   1  7
7   1  8
8   1  9
9   1 10
10  2  3
11  2  4
12  2  5
13  2  6
14  2  7
15  2  8
16  2  9
17  2 10
18  2 11
```